# 2.8 box selection does not select everything, tiny objects not selected?

Tags: objects, select

I have a lot of problems with box selection on objects,
there are always not all objects selected !!

I don't have any fancy collections or wrong settings in the outliner,
also when I zoom in - I can select them - whats wrong !?

[image]

Comment: can you supply an example file with viewport set to recreate the issue?  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Sounds like it might be a bug.

Comment: yeah, I can confirm it's like a depth when selecting, when I zoom-in can select those smaller objects

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6549" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6549/)

Comment: use this demo file just broder select the geometry from this zoom level (do not zoom in) and do a grab (g x) - a lot of obejcts are not moving (cause not selected) !

Comment: the same with behaviour with
Blender 2.81 Alpha
September 11, 23:12:23 - 1e375ab5a104

Comment: ... BUT working as expected with old 2.79

Comment: I can confirm replication of the issue with your .blend. Very odd, Othorgraphic view and mucking about with the view clipping made no difference. I think you need to report it as a bug. https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports

Answer (score 1):

When I use "Origins (All)" - selection works ....

^ I try to find an example, because I'can't supply this (customer) data ...

[image]